# Make graduated symbol values exceed what exists in the data

Tags: qgis, symbology

[image: Graduated Symbology, Equal Interval]

Currently the symbol values stop at 62 since it is the highest value in the data, I want to extend this limit to 100 (as these values are supposed to be percentages)

I understand that the colours from 62-100 will not show up on the map as no boundaries reach that high, but I need the colours to be on the same scale as other maps (which do reach 100)

Basically I want to be able to have 50 equal interval classes from 0-100, even though the highest point in the data is 62.

Answer (score 2):

In the attribute table, you can create an entry, with the value of 100. If you do that, it will not have a geometry, so nothing appears on the map. But when you classified your legend, it will go to 100 as max value!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this feature is missing.

You need to go a little workaround:

1. create a new numeric field in your dataset
2. add a value to two features, one with 0 and one with 100
3. create your classification by this new field
4. now change the field to your actual field **and do not press classify again**
5. you can now delete your new numeric field

[image]

Comment: Then save the style as "fixed-0-100" for later use?

Comment: Sure, you can do that.